# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'] with root cause

Tags: java, mysql

When I try to insert data into database i got below error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path []
>   threw 
>       exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: 
>       com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>
> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'] with root cause
>       com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>
> Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

this is my query

```
insert into tablename values(0,'(col name)');
```

Answer (score 1):

The first column of the table is a primary key. So duplicate values are not allowed in it. But from your SQL query, I understand you are passing 0 as hard code value for every time.
This is the reason for the error.

Comment: @poonam Because a few days ago, there is not a row which primary key is 0. After that, there is such a row. So you cannot insert another.

Comment: Previously when I was using the same query,Id was auto incremented instead of "0" it was correctly accepting auto incremented id it was working fine but now it is giving me above error.

Comment: @poonam May someone modified the table?

Comment: No sir, no one modified table structure.

Comment: @poonam If the Id is an auto increment column, you no need to pass any value explicitly to that particular column.

Answer (score 0):

quick fix to this will be 
1. first take a sqldump for safety purpose.
2. truncate the table and get sqldump which gives the duplicate key issue.
3. create new schema from the dump.
now try you are good to go.